# Get value of 4 divs by :first, :second, :nth - jQuery

Tags: jquery

How do I get the value of

```
<div>
    <span class="xxx" id="VariesAlways">x1</span>
    <span class="xxx" id="VariesAlways">x2</span>
    <span class="xxx" id="VariesAlways">x3</span>
    <span class="xxx" id="VariesAlways">x4</span>
</div>
```

Normaly

```
$('.xxx').trigger(function() {

    $(this).attr('value');
});
```

But I want it as

```
$('.xxx:first').attr('value');
$('.xxx:second').attr('value');
$('.xxx:third').attr('value');
$('.xxx:fourth').attr('value');
```

But when an `alert($('.xxx:first').attr('value'));` is done it gives me undefined.

Thanks
Jean

Comment: Dude your ID's should be unique :)

Comment: might be because it has no `value` attribute.

Comment: @simevidas, it is unique, which is why I said varies Always
@jAndy it has a value x1,x2,x3,x4

Comment: btw you can use eq(): `$('.xxx').eq(2)` would give you the third span element

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, `.attr('value')` will not work if the element has no attribute `value`.. Thats for sure :)

To select them by the order you want, you should use either the `:eq` pseudo selector or, better (=faster) the `.eq()` method.

```
$('span.xxx').eq(0).text()
$('span.xxx').eq(1).text()
$('span.xxx').eq(2).text()
$('span.xxx').eq(3).text()
```

`.eq()` needs the index as parameter.
Anyway, you also can just loop over them by invoking `.each()`

```
$('span.xxx').each(function(index, elem) {
    alert(elem.textContent || elem.text);
});
```

`.each()` will loop over the nodes as they appear in the DOM. To its probably the better way to go.

Reference: [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Answer (score 2):

`<span>` tags don't have a `value` attribute.  You want to use [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/). or [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
$('.xxx:first').text();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [:nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

```
$('.xxx:nth-child(i)').text()
```

where i = {1,2,3,4} (note that the counting starts at 1)

Answer (score 0):

I think you first need to make you id's unique and then something like:

```
$('.xxx').trigger(function() 
{      
       var content = $(this).text();
});
```

So to expand on your example:

```
alert($('.xxx:first').text());
```